# Blackberry launch native web browser

Tags: browser, blackberry

How can I open a URL from BlackBerry ?
in J2ME I am using:

```
this.platformRequest("http://www.google.com");
```

How can I do this on BlackBerry?

Comment: The solution:
http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Create_a_web_icon.html?nodeid=1487655&vernum=0

Thk!!!

Answer (score 17):

If you want to launch a browser session you would use:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://www.google.com");
```

If you want to open, and then read the returned data for processing yourself:

```
HttpConnection google = (HttpConnection)javax.microedition.io.Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
int rc = google.getResponceCode();
...
InputStream is = google.openInputStream();
```

You do need to make sure that processing the connection and returned data does not happen on the event thread or your blackberry will hang.

Comment: Or worse, crash! (if you're using a TCP connection instead of a BES or BIS connection)

Answer (score 15):

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://www.google.com");
```

is the correct way to launch the BlackBerry browser with your URL.

Comment: people should vote for Richard's answer, instead, as this one merely copied it.

Answer (score 5):

well i think kozen is right but u can go ahead like this,may be......

```
BrowserSession bSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
bSession.displayPage(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BrowserSession myBrowser = Browser.getDefaultSession();
myBrowser.displayPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

or

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```