# Install third-party BlackBerry app when my app is installed

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

I want to install the Google Maps app when installing my application.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any control (i.e. can't run any code) during the installation process.  You could check for dependencies at application startup time (i.e. check for the Google Maps module) and if its missing, [automatically open a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614526/blackberry-launch-native-web-browser) to the Google Maps install page.