# BlackBerry can you call up the web browser from java?

Tags: blackberry

I’m writing a app for the blackberry and would like to call up the built in browser, can you do this?

Comment: Do you mean to just launch it?

Comment: Already asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614526/blackberry-launch-native-web-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a Midlet, use the [platformRequest](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest%28java.lang.String%29) method to do this.

If you are building a blackberry app, you can use:

```
BrowserSession browser = Browser.getDefaultSession();
browser.displayPage(url);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help, it almost works.  The first line has a yellow line under it saying Signature equred protected class. and the 2nd line is under line with a red, saying browser csannot be resolved.  I'm using eclipse and saw a option for signe with signature tool, but it is greyed out.