# BlackBerry POST requests via builtin browser

Tags: http, blackberry, browser

In my BlackBerry application I need to make some HTTP request using the builtin browser.

Thanks to [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/614526/1485859), I managed to make some GET requests.

Now, my question is: what about making POST requests?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore the class [`BrowserField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html).

You can use following methods:

- `void` [`requestContent`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html#requestContent%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5b%5d,%20java.util.Hashtable%29) `(String url, byte[] postData, Hashtable requestHeaders)`
- `void` [`requestContent`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html#requestContent%28net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserFieldRequest%29) `(`[`BrowserFieldRequest`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldRequest.html) `request)`